# Blazor download html string as Image

Tags: c#, html, image, download, blazor

```
public async Task ExportGraph(string projectName, string html)
{            
    var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);

    using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
               
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: stream);

    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", $"FazerGraph-{projectName}.jpg", streamRef);
}
```

I have this method that receives a string containing the html I want to create an image from.
I-m getting this string from this JS method:

```
function getInnerHTMLElement(element) {
    if (element) {
        return element.innerHTML;
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I download the jpg image and try to open it says:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using now html converter like this:

```
    public async Task ExportGraph(string projectName, string html)
    {
        var converter = new HtmlConverter();

        var bytes = converter.FromHtmlString(html);
        
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                   
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: stream);

        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", $"FazerGraph-{projectName}.jpg", streamRef);
    }
```

and the result image I get is this:

[image]

What can I do to make it the same look like the html (shown bellow)?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  What image are you expecting to see there?  A rendering of the HTML string you saved to the stream?  HTML saved to bytes is obviously not a valid image format, certainly not a JPG.

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for the feedback I updated my question

Comment: With your updated question, one example shows a broken image (expected) and your other example using `HtmlConverter` is apparently showing the image (seems right)?  What do you mean, "What can I do to make it the same?"

Comment: @KirkWoll sorry, added now the expected result

Comment: I'm not sure what library `HtmlConverter` is a part of (possibly iText7?), but your problem is with this library, so you'd be best off focusing on that.  Converting HTML to an image is a job for a proper web browser, and most libraries of this sort do a poor job when compared against a browser's results.  There's probably some tweaks you can try, but I expect your results when compared to what you see in the browser are going to be imperfect.

Comment: @KirkWoll The library I'm using is CoreHtmlToImage, it is one of the most downloaded libraries for that purpose

Comment: Sure, I just meant your focus for help should be around using this library, as the other technologies you've tagged aren't going to garner much useful attention.  That said, your main problem appears to me that you are getting the inner HTML of an arbitrary element and trying to convert that to an image.  This would necessarily bypass all CSS styling (since the style sheet would be unknown) and appears to match the problems shown in your problematic image.

Comment: @KirkWoll I already wrote inline css and makes no diference, so I don't know what could be done

Comment: it's clearly a styling issue.  In any case, you may want to look at a library that uses the browser itself to generate the image, as that would guarantee pixel perfect output.  I took a quick look at [this library](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and it seems like the tack I'd take if I were you.